# Data Compression for versions that don't support sp_estimate_data_compression_savings

Tags: sql, azure, compression

Is it possible to make some estimation for data compression in SQL databases for cases when sp_estimate_data_compression_savings  isn't supported?

How can I estimate data compression for Azure Databases?